# non member function template of a template class

Tags: c++

```
    template <class T>
    class BTree
    {
    private:
        T Data;
        BTree* Right;
        BTree* Left;
    public:
        BTree();
        BTree(T);
        ~BTree();
        void SetData(T);
        T GetData();
        void SetRight(BTree*);
        BTree* GetRight();
        void SetLeft(BTree*);
        BTree* GetLeft();
    };
```

Is this the way to declare a non member function template?I seriously have some doubts about these definitions.

```
    template <class T>
    BTree<T>* NewNode();
    template <class T>
    BTree<T>* NewNode(T);
```

this below does not work!! gives me an error

```
template <class T>
BTree<T>* NewNode()
{
    BTree<T>* Node=new BTree<T>;
    return Node;
}

    template <class T=int>
    //template <class BTree>
    BTree<T>* NewNode(T Num)
    {
        BTree<T>* Node=new BTree<T>(Num);
        return Node;
    }


    int main()
    {

        BTree<int>* Root=NULL;
        Root=NewNode(1); //it says undefined reference.
        Root->SetLeft(NewNode(2));
        Root->SetRight(NewNode(3));
        return 0;
    }
```

The error is as the following:

```
1.undefined reference to `BTree<int>* NewNode<int>(int)'
2.undefined reference to `BTree<int>::SetLeft(BTree<int>*)'
3.undefined reference to `BTree<int>::SetRight(BTree<int>*)'
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/IdaoGc) once I provide definitions for `BTree`'s methods being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: This is a linker error, not a compiler error. See n.m.'s link for why and how to fix it. Your declarations are fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked once I defined everything in the header file.